# Radius of convergence of Eisenstein series

Tags: power-series, modular-forms, modular-function

The Eisenstein series $E_k$ on the upper half plane $\mathbb H$ are holomorphic, $1$-periodic and therefore allow a Fourier series
$$E_k(\tau)=1-\frac{2k}{B_k}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sigma_{k-1}(n)q^n, \quad q=e^{2\pi i\tau},$$
with $k\geq2$ even, $B_k$ the Bernouilli numbers and $\sigma$ the divisor function. This is also the Taylor series at $\tau=i\infty$ or $q=0$, respectively. Let us consider $E_4$ as an example. In order to check the radius of convergence, we can use the ratio test. If the series converges on the whole $\mathbb H$, the radius of convergence has to be at least 1. However, one can check numerically that $\frac{\sigma_3(n+1)}{\sigma_3(n)}$ does not approach 1 for $n\to\infty$. Does that mean the $q$-series of $E_4$ does not converge on the whole $\mathbb H$ or is there a flaw in my argument?
Thanks a lot for a quick answer!

Comment: the ratio test is an implication, not equivalence (to see that $E_k$ converges when $|q|<1$ simply notice that $\sigma_{k-1}(n)\leq n^k$)

Comment: @user8268 I see, the problem is that the quotient does not converge. It seems that the test with limsup and liminf is also inconclusive. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think the root test works.

Comment: @AnginaSeng You're right, thank you!

Comment: $\sum_n a_n z^n$ converges for $|z|<1$ iff $a_n r^n\to 0$ for all $r >1$ (comparison with geometric series). And the main theorem (follows from Cauchy integral formula) is that $E_k(\frac{\log q}{2i\pi })$ is holomorphic for $|z|<1$ implies that its Taylor series converges (to it) there. $q\to \frac{\log q}{2i\pi }$ is the chart of the modular curve at $i\infty$.

Comment: I am also interested in the function $\sqrt{E_4}$ where the square root is defined through its Taylor series. The $q$-series is then still integral. However, with any of the above methods I find that the radius of convergence is only around $|q|<0.004$ such that the $q$-series converges if $\text{Im}(\tau)>0.878$. Are you aware of any way to compute the radius of converge analytically, and if such a function could be turned into a holomorphic function by on $\mathbb H$ by gluing regions of convergence together (using the $S$-transformation for instance)?